# How can we compare two XML API responses in karate framework without considering Date tag in it

Tags: karate

If i am saving two responses with different data in a * def variable. Then how can i compare these two without considering date or few tags data in it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to show with an example of what you have done and where you need help so it can be answered better.

You can [set](https://github.com/intuit/karate#set) the values of such nodes to an empty string and then compare:

```
set cat /cat/name = ""
```

Comment: Thanks Neodawn,
Actually, i am trying to compare 2 different xml responses (Currently, using the match attribute). But as karate finds the first occurrence of different data, it stops there itself and does not compare further for other remaining tags in xml file. Is there any way, i can get a complete detail reflected in report of all the tags with different data.

Comment: You cannot get all the mismatches in one run in karate as that is how it is designed. When you encounter the first issue, add a line of code to either set them as blanks or remove the nodes in both the XMLs and then do the match. Repeat the process until there are no mismatches. Other option is to write your own Javascript/Java XMLDiff function to return all the mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an expected response XML as file, you can easily use the #ignore tag which is supplied by Karate.

For example:

```
< Date_time >#ignore< / Date_time >
```

When you compare the file on your disk with the actual response Karate will ignore the #ignore tags.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Richard, I am not having expected XML as a file. Sending two request and getting two responses and directly need to compare each other.